# Can I send an iMessage to a iPad user from my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ipad, messages

I'm amazed I can't figure this out - my friend has an iPad running iOS5. He can send me an iMessage to my phone using my AppleID. But (outside of replying to his message) there is no way for me to send him a message using the Message app, since it only lets me enter phone numbers.

So, how does an iPhone user send an iMessage to an iPad user's AppleID?

EDIT: Does this work for anyone else?
ON AN IPHONE (3GS, if it matters, running iOS 5), open Messages. 
Hit the 'Compose' button. 
Try to type in an email address in the 'To' field.

There is NO WAY to enter an email address there, afaict

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How does an iPhone send iMessages to iPad:

1. Make sure iMessage is set "on" on both devices
2. On your iPhone, go to Contacts and find your friend's name to check whether or not you have his email address. If not, you need to add his email address.
3. On the iPad, go to settings>>messages>>recieve at>>add email. Put your friend's email address from step 2. It will say "verify".
4. Your friend need to verify by checking his email. There'll be an email from Apple. Open the email and he'll be asked to click on the verify link. Click on it and he'll be directed to Apple's homepage. Just follow the instructions there.
5. Once your friend has verified his email address, the word "verify" in step 3 disappears. Now you can iMessage him.
6. On your iPhone, go to contacts and choose your friend's name. Click on "send message" and choose the email address that was just verified. You're now directed to the message screen.
7. In the "To" field, you 'll see that the email adress is missing "@". Ignore it.
8. Make sure that the send button is blue. Now just type your message and send.

Hope this works!

Comment: That works - it's amazing that Apple would make it so complicated. If you select the friend's email address, it does NOT work. You must select 'Send Message' and then choose email, like mentioned above. Also, the fact that '@' doesn't appear is an amazing bug.

Answer (score 2):

psychotik, I think I figured this out. I was having the exact same problem as you. There was no way to type an '@' sign, and selecting from the contact list inside Messages app **only** shows phone numbers. I had to turn on "MMS Messaging" in Settings > Messages.

This enabled the @ sign on the keyboard for me. See:

[image: user's keyboard]

I have no idea why this affects it. I feel like MMS should have nothing to do with whether I can iMessage someone, but it works for me, so I won't complain.

Comment: Seconded. When I enable MMS as suggested, the available selections for a contact include their email addresses, which will hook you up with iPad-only users.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure iMessage is turned on on your iPhone; then just create a new message and in the “to” field write your friend’s iMessage address. When you type it all the title bar should change from “Message” to “iMessage”.

Comment: Huh?  Did you just type that answer thinking you know how this works, or have you actually tried this? There is no iMessage app on the phone - it's rolled into 'Messages'. Also, you can't just 'write your friend's address' in the to field -- there is no '@' character available on the keyboard. Copy-pasting doesn't work (it removed the '@') and you can't pick an email address from a contact.

Comment: Works fine here as Samantha suggests.

Comment: @psychotik I tried it just yesterday on my friends iPhone, she's been iMessegeing me ever since. And I'm sure they are iMesseges and not normal texts because I only have an iPad

Comment: Also I had no troubles finding the @ on the keyboard

Comment: I also didn't say make sure iMessege is on your iPhone but make sure iMessege is on on your iPhone i.e. you have to turn it on

Comment: I can reply to an iMessage if my friend sends it from his iPad. I cannot compose a brand new message to send him. For instance, ON AN IPHONE (3GS, if it matters, running iOS 5), open Messages. Hit the 'Compose' button. Try to type in an email address. There is NO WAY to enter an email address there. Is it just my phone that's busted?

Comment: Also, FWIW, I can successfully send iMessages to friends who have iPhone using their phone numbers (I see the blue bubbles and the iMessage prompt in the text field)

Comment: You also need to have an Apple ID associated with your iMessage.

Comment: @Ahmad Gaffoor I do

Comment: @SamanthaCatania look at the marked answer - what you have here isn't how it's done. '@' doesn't even exist in the 'To' field like I mentioned previously.